# Не отображаются картинки в ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Изучаю node, express, mongodb, ejs. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не отображаются картинки. Ниже прикреплю материал.

```html
<img src="../pages/img/cart.png" alt="" class="head__log-img">
```

Возможно это очень легко исправляется, но я понять не могу
Структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="/img/cart.png" alt="" class="head__log-img">
```

или так

```
<img src="img/cart.png" alt="" class="head__log-img">
```